# Connecting to SQL on Cloud

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, cloud, vba

I have an excel report that currently pulls data from our in house SQL server into Excel via this report. To make the connection I have a dropdown box that is populated with the server name using the Workbook_Open() sub. Once the user selects the server. The code below is kicked off to bring back a list of all available databases for the user to select.

This has always worked fine on the in house server and is a piece of code I have replicated for many reports over many years. However our company has just moved to a hosted/cloud based SQL server and IT have given me all relevant permissions and I have accessed the server via credential manager.

However every time I run the code I get the following error:

[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen(Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

I know it sounds obvious but I have had the tech guys look at it and they get the same error even though permissions are granted. If I jump onto management studio I can access the server. Its just when I try to pull it through via Excel?

Any thoughts/advice would be much appreciated as I have never seen this error and do not know where to go.

```
Private Sub CB_Server_Change()

With Application
    .Calculation = xlManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Dim stSQL As String, rst As ADODB.Recordset, k As Integer, vaData As Variant
Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim ConnectionString As String, sServer As String
ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb.1;data source=" & sServer & ";Initial catalog=master;Integrated Security = SSPI;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection

sServer = "[" & CB_Server & "]"

If sServer = "[Select Server]" Then

MsgBox "Please Select Server", vbExclamation, "Geo Server"

Exit Sub

End If

stSQL = "EXEC ('SELECT NAME " & _
                "FROM " & sServer & ".master.dbo.sysdatabases " & _
                "WHERE NAME LIKE ''%US%'' AND NAME LIKE ''%UK%'' " & _
                "ORDER BY NAME')"

With objConn
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open ConnectionString
    '.Open "Provider=sqloledb.1;data source==" & sServer & ";Initial catalog=Master;Integrated Security = SSPI;"
    .CommandTimeout = 300
     'Instantiate the Recordsetobject and execute the SQL-state.
    Set rst = .Execute(stSQL)
End With


With rst
    Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing 'Disconnect the recordset.
    k = .Fields.Count
          'Populate the array with the whole recordset.
    vaData = .GetRows
End With

CB_EDM.List = Application.Transpose(vaData)

'Close the connection.
objConn.Close

'Release objects from memory.
Set rst = Nothing
Set objConn = Nothing

bClear = True

'Restore the settings.
With Application
    .Calculation = xlAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What cloud provider? Azure?

Comment: Thanks Alex, yes this is on Azure

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is trying to use the variable sServer before it's assigned a value.  Assuming that the rest of the connection inputs are valid, try using

```
sServer = "[" & CB_Server & "]"
ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb.1;data source=" & sServer & ";Initial catalog=master;Integrated Security = SSPI;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I added in this code and now get a different error. Run-time error '-2147467259(80004005) Automation error Unspecified Error?????